# Search Box Web Part Width

Tags: web-part, search-box

Could someone tell me how I can (using CSS) change the width of the Search Box web part to 550px?

As you will see from the picture below, I need the width of the Search Box web part to align with the icons above it.

[image]

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, either should work:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fb688c9c-6876-42f8-8d06-8e1a0e069abf/search-box-web-part-size?forum=sharepointadmin

http://www.geekmungus.co.uk/general-it/changesizeofsearchboxwebpart-sharepoint2013

Comment: I do this but then the search box now has a height of 60px rather than 30px. For some reason the magnifying glass symbol is moved down a line.

Comment: This is what mine looks like with the specs you gave:  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDr1N.jpg

Comment: yeah mine is that height too however the text and search magnifier icon should be aligned as well.

Comment: You may need to use your DOM explorer to specifically target the magnifying glass.